# Avoid duplicates columns with left join sqldf

Tags: r, left-join, sqldf

I'm trying to do a left join using sqldf package on R.

```
data <- sqldf(
" SELECT a.*, b.var1, b.var2, b.id 
FROM table1 as a LEFT JOIN table2 as b 
ON a.id=b.id "
)
```

Unfortunately I get two columns named "id" in data. How can I avoid this problem?

Thanks

Chloé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the code is asking for two id's as `a.*` includes all `a` columns and it explicitly asked for `b.id`.  You can simply drop the `b.id`

```
library(sqldf)
# test inputs
table1 <- data.frame(id = 0, a = 3)
table2 <- data.frame(id = 0, var1 = 1, var2 = 2)

sqldf(
  " SELECT a.*, b.var1, b.var2
    FROM table1 as a LEFT JOIN table2 as b 
    ON a.id = b.id "
)
##   id a var1 var2
## 1  0 3    1    2
```

or if you want all `b` columns except id then use `USING` instead of `ON`

```
sqldf(
  " SELECT *
    FROM table1 as a LEFT JOIN table2 as b 
    USING(id) "
)
##   id a var1 var2
## 1  0 3    1    2
```

If you do want two id's but just named differently then this will name the `b.id` as `id2`.

```
sqldf(
  " SELECT a.*, b.var1, b.var2, b.id as id2
  FROM table1 as a LEFT JOIN table2 as b 
  ON a.id=b.id "
)
##   id a var1 var2 id2
## 1  0 3    1    2   0
```

Comment: Thanks ! I only tried the first solution because I do a left join on multiple variables and with condition in the "on" statement. I don't know if it works with using